# Microsoft Print to PDF overrides Selenium Preferences (Python)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pdf, webdriver

I am using Selenium to scrape an external web page and download a PDF for automated data analysis. Unfortunately, the website has an internal PDF viewer, meaning I must set it's preferences to avoid the print dialog and immediately bring up the download screen. However, in this step, the preference I specified for saving as a PDF fails and is overridden by the Microsoft Print to PDF option, which deletes the XML encodings that exist in the text which disables my data analysis ability. Does anyone have any solutions to this error, or is my code just faulty?

Here is my code for setting up the preferences and for initiating the print dialog:

```
url = 'google.com' #url of the login page, actual link differs from this

webdriver_service = Service('C:/Users/liamw/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': {
        'recentDestinations': [{
            'id': 'Save as PDF',
            'origin': 'local'
        }],
        'selectedDestinationId': 'Save as PDF',
        'version': 2
    },
    'savefile.default_directory': 'C:/Users/liamw/Downloads/CAM Download Directory'
})

chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = webdriver_service, options = chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
...
driver.execute_script("window.print();")
```

I tried playing around with different preference options to no success. I thought it would change the error and work as expected but to no avail. Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added some webdriver code initialization that I previously left out...apologies for the lack of clarity. Setting up my webdriver should be entirely reproducible currently.

Answer (score 0):

What is missing from your code is the flag **account** inside the **recentDestinations** flag’s value list, append it after **origin**:

```
…
“origin”: “local”,
“account”: “”
```

Otherwise I see you did not put an **r** in-front of your Windows paths which uses backslashes as directory separators. Python uses backslash for special commands such as **\n** for a newline or **\t** for a tab. Either add **r** in-front of the string or add double backslashes instead of one so you escape the second one, you could also user forward slashes python will understand it’s a path. Here is an example using **r**:

```
r“C:\MyPath\ToSomeWhere”
```

You could also add **driver.implicitly_wait(60)** (60 seconds) to help, it will add a timeout for the **driver** to stop (raise an error) if over that amount of seconds but also it will not wait for that amount to proceed with other commands.

In case this can help OP or anyone, have a look at my answer in this similar thread: [Selenium chromedriver download webpage is not saving as a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013171/selenium-chromedriver-download-webpage-is-not-saving-as-a-pdf/78038242#78038242)

Comment: Thanks for guidance Yunnosch, not sure why on the downvote though, but I am just trying to help here. Also, is not a duplicate but rather similar in interest, that can both benefit from a working script. I do understand I should add a more descriptive answer and not just a link, I edited my answer.