# Selenium chromedriver download webpage is not saving as a PDF

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pdf-generation

I'm using selenium's chrome webdriver to open up a webpage and then save that webpage to a file location on my local drive.  For some reason, the script ('window.print();') will open up the save as webpage option, but it won't proceed to click "print" and save the file locally.  The JavaScript just never seems to complete and it times out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

pdf_path = "C:\\Test_Data\\output.pdf"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

time.sleep(5)

driver.set_script_timeout(5)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

I've tried increasing the timeouts but it never really completes the process.

Comment: _but it won't proceed to click "print" and save the file locally_  What do you mean?  There is no code here to click on a button.  How are you expecting the button to be clicked?

Comment: I was under the impression that this would execute a script to run through that process.

driver.execute_script('window.print();')

Comment: So you were expecting that the print button would just somehow, magically, get clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing if the OP actually wants to “Print to PDF” or “Save as PDF” which is a huge difference in output, then K J’s comment would be appropriate.

If you really want to stick with selenium you should add `implicitly_wait(number_of_seconds)` and also add `chrome_options.add_argument("—kiosk-printing")`.

Implicitly wait will wait for your `driver.get(“https://www.google.com")` and `driver.execute_script('window.print();')` commands to finish executing and `simplicitpy_wait` should only be added once. The other command `--kiosk-printing` that will automatically click the print button for you. For some reason if you get an error on the `driver.get` just add a **try/except** for either your whole function or just the `driver.get` command.

I suggest to keep a few sleep commands (might not even be necessary), but I haven’t done lots of testing with big pdf files, just beware. Also I should point out to add a long enough delay in the `implicitly_wait` command since it is just a timeout rather than strictly wait that amount of seconds.

If you are looking for “**Save as PDF**” let me know I am working on a solution as well and it’s almost ready.

***Edit**: Remove the `--disable-gpu` argument and the `script_timeout` command from your code, and since you are not using service at the moment the from/import for the service can also be removed.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick script I was able to make today that will **Save as PDF** with selenium/chromedriver, hopefully it can help OP or point someone in the right direction.

It should work on Windows/Linux/Mac but feel free to customize, improve or simplify it as needed, here is the script:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
import subprocess
import platform
import glob
import json
import time
import os

def ChromeDriver_Save_as_PDF(URL_or_FilePath = "", PDF_FileName = "", DownloadPath = "", TimeOut = 300, Background_Graphics = True, Headers_Footers = False, Hide_Window = True):
    try:
        if URL_or_FilePath == "": 
            return "Aborted, there was no URL or PATH provided."
        
        if os.path.isfile(URL_or_FilePath): 
            URL_or_FilePath = f"file:///{URL_or_FilePath}"
        
        if DownloadPath == "":
            ScriptPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
            DownloadPath = ScriptPath
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(DownloadPath):
                os.makedirs(DownloadPath)
        DownloadPath = os.path.normpath(DownloadPath)
        try:
            command = 'where' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else 'which'
            ChromeDriver_Path = subprocess.check_output([command, 'chromedriver']).decode('utf-8').strip()
            DriverPaths = ChromeDriver_Path.split(“\r\n”)
            if len(DriverPaths) > 1:
                ChromeDriver_Path = DriverPaths[0]
        except:
            ChromeDriver_Path = os.path.join(f"{DownloadPath}","chromedriver.exe")
        
        if not os.path.isfile(ChromeDriver_Path):
            return f"Aborted, chromedriver.exe was not found. Please add it's path to your system's environment PATH or simply place it in the same directory as this script."
        settings = {"recentDestinations"    : [{"id":       "Save as PDF",
                                                "origin":   "local",
                                                "account":  ""}],
                    "selectedDestinationId" : "Save as PDF",
                    "isCssBackgroundEnabled": Background_Graphics, # Enabled Background Graphics
                    "isHeaderFooterEnabled" : Headers_Footers,     # Disable Footers & Headers
                    "version"               : 2}
                
        prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState'     : json.dumps(settings), 
                 'savefile.default_directory'                          : DownloadPath}
        
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) # Mute all log output
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs) # Add our custom settings
        chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing') # Automatically print/save when the print dialog appears
        chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")    # Log only "Fatal" Errors
        service = Service(ChromeDriver_Path)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        if Hide_Window:
            driver.set_window_position(-100000, -100000) # Hide the window, do not minimize if you have javascript!
        driver.implicitly_wait(TimeOut) # 300 Seconds (wait "up" to 5 minutes for execution of commands, etc...)
        driver.get(URL_or_FilePath)
        while driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") != "complete":
            time.sleep(1)
        pdf_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(DownloadPath, "*.pdf"))
        pdf_file_count = len(pdf_files)
        try:
            driver.execute_script('window.print();')
        except:
            pass
        
        start_time = time.time()
        
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            pdf_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(DownloadPath, "*.pdf"))
            if len(pdf_files) > pdf_file_count:
                if PDF_FileName != "":
                    pdf_files.sort(key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
                    last_created_file = pdf_files[0]
                    if not PDF_FileName.endswith('.pdf'):
                        PDF_FileName += '.pdf'
                    time.sleep(1)
                    os.rename(last_created_file, os.path.join(DownloadPath, PDF_FileName))
                break
            if time.time() - start_time > TimeOut:
                return "Aborted, the PDF was not created within the specified TimeOut limit."
            
        driver.quit()
        return "PDF was created & saved successfully."
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {e}"
    
#####################
### Example Usage ###
#####################
    
# Required Variables
Target_URL = "https://www.example.com/"

# Optional Variables (do not need to be supplied)
Save_PDF_FileName           = "My_PFD_FileName.pdf"
Save_Download_Dir           = "C:\\Temp" # or "C:/Temp" or r"C:\Temp" will also work
TimeOut_Limit               = 120        # 2 Minutes
Enable_Background_Graphics  = True
Enable_Headers_Footers      = False
Hide_Chrome_Window          = True       # if there is javascript code, don't minimize the window, just hide it

# Example #1 URL
Save_Status = ChromeDriver_Save_as_PDF(Target_URL)
print(f"{Save_Status}")

# Example #2 File Path (any type of files a web browser can open and view)
'''
Target_FilePath = r"C:\Temp\saved_webpage.html"
Save_Status = ChromeDriver_Save_as_PDF( Target_FilePath, 
                                        Save_PDF_FileName, 
                                        Save_Download_Dir, 
                                        TimeOut_Limit, 
                                        Enable_Background_Graphics, 
                                        Enable_Headers_Footers, 
                                        Hide_Chrome_Window)
print(f"{Save_Status}")
'''
```