# Is there any way to save in PDF automatically the website with window.print() or Ctrl+P in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-profile, firefox-headless

When I am on any web page (e.g https://stackoverflow.com/) I would like to save it in PDF automatically from Firefox with 'Mozilla Save to PDF'. For example Ctrl+P or `window.print()` method from console.

I use these configs (about:config and about:preferences):

`browser.download.folderList "2" browser.download.dir "/path/to/download/directory" browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk "*" print_printer "Mozilla Save to PDF" print.always_print_silent "true"`

`Always ask you where to save files -> not checked Content-type PDF -> Save file in the Applications section`

When I use the Ctrl+P hotkey or `window.print()`, not happened enything.

I have tried the metioned above configs. Could you give some suggessions?
I have to use it in manual and selenium-js tests.

Comment: I have not been using headless mode. in my opinion the normal mode more stable in tests. I have to use it in ERP software when the software create an invoice, automatically print it in pdf. I want to automate the print preview window

Comment: If it can help, have a look at my answer in a similar thread here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013171/selenium-chromedriver-download-webpage-is-not-saving-as-a-pdf/78038242#78038242](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013171/selenium-chromedriver-download-webpage-is-not-saving-as-a-pdf/78038242#78038242)